# Javascript file not loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
public function __construct() {

            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'my_init_method' ));
    }
```

And registered a custom javascript file:

```
public function my_init_method()
    {   
        wp_register_script ( 'bt_custom_javascript', plugins_url ( 'assets/custom.js', __FILE__ ) );
    }
```

Before using with

```
 wp_enqueue_script('bt_custom_javascript');
```

but the script is never loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you enqueue 'bt_custom_javascript' ?

Comment: @VidyaL inside of `add_submenu_page` callback function.

Comment: are you developing a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
public function __construct() {

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'my_init_method' ));
}

public function my_init_method()
{   
 wp_register_script ( 'bt_custom_javascript', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'assets/custom.js',array(), '1.0.0', true  );
 wp_enqueue_script ( 'bt_custom_javascript' );
}
```